# Validacion de Datos GroupBy

Tags: python, validación, pandas, ciencia-de-datos

Es necesario agrupar los items por nombre

[image: tabla_cruda]

Después hay que ver que todos los que tengan los nombres iguales también coincidan en el RREF1, RREF2, RREF3 y si no son iguales en los RREF que diga cuales.

```
# Agrupacion por valores similares en columna, resta de valores entre dos columnas

cond1_df = (
    mydataset_df
    .groupby(["name"], as_index=False).sum()
    .assign(
        validacion=lambda row: row.RREF3 == row.RREF3
    )


)
cond1_df.head(10)
```

algo que deberia salir es:

[image: salida]

pero en validacion decirme cuales valores no son iguales

Comment: fjsevilla ___ corregido, gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partiremos primero de un DataFrame como el que muestras para poder reproducir el problema:

```
import pandas as pd


data = {"name": ("Babero", "Babero Terry", "Babero Terry", "Baly", "Baly", "Baly", "Barilla Metalica", "Base Para Portátil", "Base Para Portátil", "Base Para Portátil"),
        "ref": (8090, 6089, 8089, 3045, 3046, 3047, 141, 7188, 7190, 7191),
        "RREF1": (1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1),
        "RREF2": (7, 6, 7, 7, 7, 0, 6, 7, 7, 7),
        "RREF3": (18, 1, 18, 15, 1, 0, 9, 18, 18, 18)
        }

mydataset_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Una opción es usar `transform` junto a [`pandas.DataFrame.nunique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html) para conseguir lo que quieres:

```
mydataset_df["Válido"] = (mydataset_df.groupby(["name"], as_index=False)
                                      ["RREF1", "RREF2", "RREF3"]
                                      .transform("nunique", dropna=False)
                                      .sum(axis=1) == 3
                         )
```

El método `nunique` retorna el número de valores únicos que hay por cada columna *RREF* dentro de cada grupo. Las filas de los grupos que tengan todas sus columnas RREF iguales tendrán 1 como valor en todas las columna retornadas por `nunique`, por lo que la suma de sus columnas será 3.

El código anterior nos da el siguiente resultado:

> ```
> >>> mydataset_df
>
>                  name   ref  RREF1  RREF2  RREF3  Válido
> 0              Babero  8090      1      7     18    True
> 1        Babero Terry  6089      2      6      1   False
> 2        Babero Terry  8089      1      7     18   False
> 3                Baly  3045      1      7     15   False
> 4                Baly  3046      1      7      1   False
> 5                Baly  3047      1      0      0   False
> 6    Barilla Metalica   141      1      6      9    True
> 7  Base Para Portátil  7188      1      7     18    True
> 8  Base Para Portátil  7190      1      7     18    True
> 9  Base Para Portátil  7191      1      7     18    True
> ```

Tanto *Babero Terry* como *Baly* no son validadas ya que sus valores *RREF* no son iguales en todas las filas.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, esta excelente y eso es lo que necesitaba.... pero en mi sistema arroja este error ...... ** AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'nunique' .....** http://nimb.ws/SMKFtd

Comment: Hola Yan Chirino, ¿qué versión de Pandas usas? Puedes obtenerla con `print(pd.__version__)`. Si usas Pandas 0.20  o superiores (ahora mismo la 0.22 es la más reciente) no debes tener problemas.

Comment: pd.__version__ 0.18.1

Comment: Pues el problema es ese, considera actualizar a la versión actual de Pandas si no te crea grandes conflictos. La 0.18 tiene ya dos años, entre otras cosas le falta el método `pandas.DataFrame.nunique` que se introdujo en la 0.20 y el cual uso en este caso por desgracia.

Comment: para la version 18 segun documentacion ya existia nunique, puede que sea producto de otra cosa el problema? http://nimb.ws/uWMdIr

Comment: para la version 18 segun documentacion ya existia nunique, puede que sea producto de otra cosa el problema? http://nimb.ws/uWMdIr

Comment: Existía la implementación  para las Series pero no para los DataFrames: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nunique.html. En mi respuesta tenia el enlace equivocado a la documentación, corregido. Por las dudas el código lo he testeado en Pandas 0.20 de un entorno virtual que tengo antiguo y en pandas 0.22, sin problemas en ambos.